# Cannot open namespace in Fsharp script file

Tags: f#, namespaces, f#-3.0

When in a separate Fsharp project in a SomeLib.fs file the following code is compiled:

```
namespace SomeNameSpace
type SomeType =
    member this.SomeMember = "Some member"
```

and you want to reference and use this type in a script file like:

```
#I @"c:/pathToDll/"
#r "SomeLib.dll"
```

This is not possible, although the path to the dll is correct and I checked everything. Also when the SomeLib.fs file is in the same project and referenced by #load, you still cannot open the namespace.

I know you can put the type in a module, but I cannot do this as the type has te be used as a Wcf service type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of experimental work and surprisingly little info on the internet or in F# books I found out the following:

```
// Cannot use a relative path
//#I @"bin\Debug"
// Have to use a absolute path
#I @"C:\Development\FSharpNameSpaceTest\SomeCSharpLib\bin\Debug"
// But I can reference a Csharp dll lib
#r "SomeCSharpLib.dll"

// I cannot add a reference to an external F# library dll
// #I @"C:\Development\FSharpNameSpaceTest\NameSpace\bin\Debug"
// #r "NameSpace.dll"

// If I directly load the external fs file, it works"
#load @"C:\Development\FSharpNameSpaceTest\NameSpace\SomeNameSpace.fs"
#load "Library1.fs"

// Namespaces in both the local and the external fs files can only be openend if every single file is loaded instead of referencing the dll.
// Referencing a C# dll is no problem

open FSharpNameSpaceTest
open SomeCSharpLib
open NameSpace
```

I do not know if this is the most optimal approach but it works. What I will do is, I will create a fsx file for every project that loads the individual fs files in that project and then I will load that fsx file in the fsx file that references the project.

I still find this all very confusing and counterintuitive. But that might be my limited knowledge of the innerworks of F#

Edit: And the right and complete answer is, I didn't implement a default constructor. Still, if you do not wan't to do this, the above approach is an alternative. Thanks to Marc Sigrit.

Comment: As a side note: when you are using an #r reference who depends on an #I import, then intellisense often does not work for the types in the reference. However, when you are using an "independent" #r reference (full path, without #I), intellisense works fine. That's why I am almost never using #I, although it would be very practical otherwise...

Comment: "I cannot add a reference to an external F# library dll": Adding references to external F# library dlls is definitely possible. Sometimes you have to be careful about the order of the references. If the F# dll depends on the C# dll, you have to reference the c# dll first, then the F# dll...

Comment: @MarcSigrist I tried the code above and it definitely did not work referencing the F# dll, I can assure you. The only possibility remains that I did something stupid in the above code. I also posted a more elaborate answer and solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937387/f-and-c-sharp-web-service-cannot-open-namespace

Comment: Your type cannot be instanciated, because it has no constructor. This is different from C#, where the compiler inserts a default constructor. To add a ctor, write 'type SomeType() = ...' (with braces).

Comment: @MarcSigrist So I did something stupid after all! ;-). You are so right, thanks! I just didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows, the slashes in the import directive should be replaced by backslashes.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't matter actually. You can even mix forward and backslashes (ugly as it is though).